# C using getopt_long()

Tags: c, parsing, getopt

I have been reading how to use `getopt_long()`, and how to "Read" the multiple character options with optlong.

I need to parse the following entry from the terminal:

```
./bomb –n String –cp Integer –i Integer –c Integer –fc String
```

so before I use getoptlong, I define my short and long options:

```
 if(argc != 11){
    perror("Error en numero de argumentos \n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 const char* const short_options = "n:i:c:";
 static struct option long_options[] = {
    {"cp", 1, NULL, 'a'},
    {"fc", 1, NULL, 'b'},
    {0, 0 , 0, 0}
 };
```

my `short_options` pick up `n` with an argument (that is what the `:` is for), the same for `c` and `i`.
So the same should be applied for the long options (they both pick up arguments as well).

```
    while(opt != -1){

        opt = getopt_long(argc, argv, short_options, long_options, NULL);

        switch (opt){   
           case 'n':
           //print it

           case 'a':
          //print it
         } 
    }
```

Now the thing is, this code works perfect for when it parses `-c -i` and `-n` , it enter the case it belongs to and prints correctly.
My issue, its not working for `-cp` and `-fc`. And really I have no idea how to fix this since I haven’t work with `getopt()` before.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting [`man getopt_long`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getopt.3.html):

> The  `getopt_long()`  function  works like `getopt()` except that it also
>     accepts long options, started  with  two  dashes.

and

> `getopt_long_only()` is `like getopt_long()`, but `-` as well as `--` can
>     indicate a long option.

So you should either use `--cp` and `--fc`, or switch to `getopt_long_only`.

Comment: getopt_long_only can read both single char options (-n -i ) as well as multiple char options (-cp -fc)?

Comment: @Alessandroempire Have you tried reading the manual yourself?

Comment: ok I used getopt_long_only , since it behaves similar to. So now its entering cp case, but not the fc. which is strange. question: when I declared my long_options, when it encounters -fc its going to return a b?